# insert text into sql table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

when i insert a text into a table in sql server, rows didn't show text and show ??????

i know with blow code can correct it:

```
INSERT [dbo].[TableName] (CityName,latitude,longitude)
VALUES (N'txt',34,56)
```

but i use this code for insert :

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableName]
VALUES (@CityName,@latitude,@longitude)

sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@CityName",SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@latitude", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@longitude", SqlDbType.Int);
```

what can i do ?

thanks

Comment: why are you using CityName as `Int` ?

Comment: How come sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@CityName", SqlDbType.Int); is Int?

Comment: no. i have a mistake it is varchar

Comment: why are lat and lng varchars ?

Comment: Does the issue still exist after the update? Can you show the table schema(columns,types)?

Comment: yes. i have mistake in wrritting question here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `SqlDbType.NVarChar` as type for your `@CityName` instead of the varchar you currently use.

```
                                            \/
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@CityName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
```

Also, like Prasanna suggests, use

```
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CityName", cityName);
```

which would probably work without needing to specify the type, in your case.

Comment: @atabrizi No - you use VarChar. This uses NVarChar.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@CityName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
```

And not

```
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@CityName", SqlDbType.Int);
```

**Update**

use `SqlDbType.NVarChar` then

Comment: yes. i edit it. but my question not that. i dont know how place 'N' in first code  in seconde code

Answer (score 1):

Use **command.Parameters.AddWithValue()** instead of  command.Parameters.Add()

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into [dbo].[TableName] 
values(@CityName,@latitude,@longitude) 

sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@CityName", SqlDbType.Int); <-- CityName (int) :) 
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@latitude", SqlDbType.VarChar); 
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@longitude", SqlDbType.VarChar);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
insert into [dbo].[TableName]
values(@CityName,@latitude,@longitude)

// implicit conversion of the value
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CityName", 'txt');
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@latitude", 34);
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@longitude", 36);
```

OR

```
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@CityName", SqlDbType.VarChar); 
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@latitude", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@longitude", SqlDbType.Int);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you parameter types not reversed?

Should "@CityName" by a SqlDbType.VarChar 
and the other 2 SqlDbType.Int?

Answer (score 0):

Please use `VarChar` instead of `int` for inserting a record into the below table, because `CityName` is not an `int`:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableName]
VALUES (@CityName,@latitude,@longitude)

sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@CityName",SqlDbType.VarChar);
// Replace of 
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@CityName", SqlDbType.Int);

sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@latitude", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@longitude", SqlDbType.Int);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please , edit your connection string where UTF-8 is there and SQL Database side you have to declare 'nvarchar' instead of 'varchar' :

```
 Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;CharSet=utf8;
```